# Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function in VUEJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I'm getting this error when I try to await outside the async function `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function` and I wanted to know hich approach should I use to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
async addCoursToClassYear() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false;
    await this.$store.dispatch("academicYear/addCoursToClassYear", {
        ...this.form,
        ...this.singleYear
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.handleSuccess();
        this.closeModal();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          this.serverValidation.setMessages(error.response.data.errors);
        } else {
          this.handleError(error);
        }
      });
  })
},
```

Comment: `setTimeout(async () => {` - That should fix it.

Comment: Why `setTimeout` without delay? It will place callback in event queue, yes, but if the callback is already asynchronous what is the point in delaying it's invocation by 4ms minimum?

Comment: @DrewReese, I forgot to add the delay. But the reason I have set up `setTimout` is because I want to have the submit button to load and be disabled  for 2 seconds before submitting the request. To avoid double clicking by user.

Comment: i think you can just remove await in front of the `dispatch`. it looks no reason to use async/await in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, put async in just the function in which you using await.

```js
async addCoursToClassYear() {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    this.loading = false;
    await this.$store.dispatch("academicYear/addCoursToClassYear", {
        ...this.form,
        ...this.singleYear
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.handleSuccess();
        this.closeModal();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          this.serverValidation.setMessages(error.response.data.errors);
        } else {
          this.handleError(error);
        }
      });
  })
},
```

Comment: remember there's a side-effect, I hope you already know the side-effects of async, the promise resolving thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using await inside setTimeout. So, you need to make async setTimeout function

```
async addCoursToClassYear() {
  setTimeout(async() => {
    this.loading = false;
    await this.$store.dispatch("academicYear/addCoursToClassYear", {
        ...this.form,
        ...this.singleYear
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.handleSuccess();
        this.closeModal();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          this.serverValidation.setMessages(error.response.data.errors);
        } else {
          this.handleError(error);
        }
      });
  })
},
```

I changed

> setTimeout(() => {

To

> setTimeout(async() => {